# Inject dependency in IStartupTask for bootstrapper

Tags: ninject, bootstrapper

I am using Bootstrapper and Ninject to manage bootstrapping my application and dependency injection. This is an asp.net webapi application.

I have a simple implementation for `IStartupTask` like follows. The implementation of the ILog is been registered using Ninject. I want to know if there is a way to inject the `ILog` to the `ContextBootstrap` class?

```
public class ContextBootstrap : IStartupTask
{
    public ILog Log { get; set; }

    public ContextBootstrap(ILog log)
    {
        Log = log;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Log.Info("somehting");
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IStartupTask internally uses the registered DI container to create instance of the concrete class, so the dependencies are injected via constructor.